# How to compare asian (vietnamese / unicode) string in C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("vi-VN");

string a = "Biển Ðông";
string b = "Biển Đông";

if (a.Equals(b, StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
}
```

The two strings are identical, but I always get `false` when checking using `Equals`. If I add this to a `HashSet<string>`, then I will get two items instead of one item in the container.

Comment: they dont even match in javascript - there must be different

Comment: it looks like theres a non printable char in sample b

Comment: Neither do they in PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ð` is not `Đ` in your case.

The first "D" is the ANSI character 208 and the second one is 272.

I tested this using

```
(int)'Ð'
(int)'Đ'
```

Those are different characters which look identical, but aren't.

Comment: Damn, 30 sec appart. Well done!

Comment: Thx dude. That was fast.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, check out LINQPad. I use this tool amongst others for diagnosis. If you enter either of these lines, the expression will be evaluated so you can see which charater it is, without creating a solution in order to execute small code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Your string are composer by the following chars:

```
\u0042\u0069\u1ec3\u006e \u00d0\u00f4\u006e\u0067
                            |||
\u0042\u0069\u1ec3\u006e \u0110\u00f4\u006e\u0067
```

Answer (score 0):

By this logic you can find, which first character is different in strings. It might be useful in this case.

```
char? firstocurrenceA = string1.Zip(string2, (a, b) => new { string1 = a, string2 = b })
    .Where(x => x.string1 != x.string2)
    .Select(x => x.string1)
    .FirstOrDefault();

        char? firstocurrenceB = string1.Zip(string2, (a, b) => new { string1 = a, string2 = b })
    .Where(x => x.string1 != x.string2)
    .Select(x => x.string2)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```